# C++ implementing object equality with multiple levels of iheritance

Tags: c++

i need to implement an isEqual method to multiple objects that are have multiple levels of inheritance. For this reason i have decided to create not a interface since the method are not pure virtual but just a class that i can use later as a tag.

Those classes implement a single method isEqual.  Since i need a default behavior defined those methods are not pure virtual.

```
class A_Interface {
    virtual isEqual(shared_ptr<A_Interface> obj);
    ...
    virtual otherMethod1();
}


class B_Interface : public virtual A_Interface {
    virtual isEqual(shared_ptr<B_Interface> obj);
    ...
    virtual otherMethod2();
}


class C_Interface : public virtual B_Interface {
    virtual isEqual(shared_ptr<C_Interface> obj);
    ...
    virtual otherMethod3();
}
```

each  class implements it's own "interface like" tag class mentioned above and inherits from the parent like this:

```
class A : public virtual A_interface;
{
    isEqual(shared_ptr<A_Interface> obj){
    ...
    }
};



class B : public virtual A, 
          public virtual B_interface 
                {
    using A::isEqual;
    isEqual(shared_ptr<B_Interface> obj){
    ...
    }
};


class C : public virtual B,
          public virtual C_interface 
  {
    using B::isEqual;
    isEqual(shared_ptr<C_Interface> obj){
    ...

    bool parentIsEquals = B::isEqual(obj);

    ...
    }
};
```

In order to avoid name hinding in Class B i explicitelly declared the

```
using A::isEqual;
```

statement which solved the problem but now in class C when i want to reffer to the method "isEqual" parent class B  and explicitelly specifing it like that

```
bool parentIsEquals = B::isEqual(obj);
```

i get the error

```
"B::isEqual' is ambiguous"
```

which I also understand since i have two signatures i.e.

```
using A::isEqual;
isEqual(shared_ptr<B_Interface> obj);
```

what i do not know is how to address this issue since the argument in this case "obj" does match bought signatures. 
I would like to understand if there a better pattern/proposition of implementing this problem.

Comment: There's code smell everywhere :) What exactly do you want to compare? As and Bs and Cs and smart pointers of it? You don't need all this machinery for that.

Comment: What if I have a `std::unique_ptr<B>` and want to compare it with an `A`? What if I have a raw pointer? Or a reference? Why does your interface for equality concern itself with how its users manage object lifetimes?

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple.

With the following class hierarchy:

```
struct A     { int value1; };
struct B : A { int value2; };
struct C : B { int value3; };
```

You can define equality operators for `A`s, `B`s and `C`s

```
bool operator==(A const& lhs, A const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.value1 == rhs->value1;
}
bool operator==(B const& lhs, B const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.value2 == rhs->value2
           && static_cast<A const&>(lhs) == static_cast<A const&>(rhs);
}
bool operator==(C const& lhs, C const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.value3 == rhs->value3
           && static_cast<B const&>(lhs) == static_cast<B const&>(rhs);
}
```

With it, a bit of sugar:

```
template<class Wrapper>
bool operator==(A const& lhs, Wrapper const& rhs)
{ return lhs == *rhs; }
template<class Wrapper>
bool operator==(Wrapper const& rhs, A const& lhs)
{ return rhs == lhs; }
// and so on...
```

All those simple functions allow you a great deal of flexibility:

```
B b1{{1}, 2};
auto c2 = std::make_unique<C>(C{{{1}, 2}, 3});
bool const equals = b1 == c2; // true
```

Comment: can you explain the mening of the second template i.e. "template<class Wrapper>
bool operator==(Wrapper const& rhs, A const& lhs)
{ return rhs == lhs; }"   why do we need this?

Comment: also is there a way in c++ to force all classes that inherit from A to implement the operator==   ? i.e. to make is some kind of pure virtual operator?

Comment: @Tito the second one is the mirror image of the first, allowing both `a == b` and `b == a`. And yes, you can have pure virtual operators, but it needs to be overridden in each child class, offering no more than free functions. Don't complicate things: better have a compile-time specific error than a run-time crash about some pure virtual function call.